# Relation between weak convergence and weak solution

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

We have definition of [weak topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology) and also of [weak solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_solution)

but the thing which I do not understand is how they are related, for instance,

> Let $X$ be a Banach space, then $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ iff $f(x_n)\to f(x), \forall~ f\in X^*$

But we say $u$ is a weak solution of $Lu=f$, where $L$ is any partial differential operator if $\forall \phi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega), ~u$ satisfies $$\langle Lu,\phi\rangle=\langle f, \phi\rangle$$ 
Does it says that 
$x=y$ in weak sense iff $f(x)=f(y)\forall~ f\in X^*$ ?

Comment: In functional analysis, the word **weak** refers to things being true when evaluated against stuff in the dual space. If you have a (possibly unbounded, densely defined) operator $A$ on a Banach space $B$, then we say a weak solution of '$Ax=y$' is one which satisfies $\phi(Ax)=\phi(y)$ for all $\phi \in D(A^*)$, where $D(A^*) = \{\phi \in B^*: \phi\circ A$ is bounded $\}$. In some special instances you can prove that weak solutions must in fact be strong; in other instances, it's not easy or even false. Similarly weak convergence refers to convergence when tested against elements of dual.

Comment: @Shalop can we take $D(A^*)= C_c(\Omega)$ or $C_c^2(\Omega)$ instead of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. I mean how we know, what to take as $D(A^*)$?

Comment: Well you are correct, $C_c^{\infty}$ does not agree with $D(A^*)$ (it is strictly contained), when $A$ is a specific second-order operator like the Laplacian; but when dealing with PDE the class $C_c^{\infty}$ generally forms a "large enough" class of functions against which to test, so that the two definitions agree. I think someone will hopefully post a more enlightening answer below, explaining weak solutions better.